# Where does Eclipse store file with Menu visibility?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

On the Eclipse setup I am about to work with there is no Window element in the top menu, therefore I cannot change the menu visibility (under the Customize perspective submenu).

Which Eclipse config file stores this information?

Comment: I think in Eclipse 4 this is probably stored as part of the persisted state in the workbench.xmi file (not an easy file to change).

Comment: Do you have the "Quick Access" search bar at the top of the workbench window?  If so, you can type "Customize Perspective" there to access the settings.

Comment: @greg-449, not easy meaning I should reinstall Eclipse?

Comment: @RichardNeish Unfortunately I don't have it.

Comment: @REACHUS From the Eclipse Juno helo, you can pop up the "Quick Search" by pressing Ctrl+3.  Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `Quick Access` search bar at the top of the workbench window you can type `Customize Perspective` there to access the settings.  Otherwise you can pop up the `Quick Search` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.